Does one light a Shabbos candle for a newborn boy before his Bris or after?
As discussed here, many Ashkenazim have the custom to light an additional Shabbos candle for each child born to the family.
According to this custom, does one start lighting an additional Shabbos candle for a new born boy before his Bris?

Welcome to MiYodeya Anthony and thanks for this first question. Your question was closed because this site is not a good place for personal questions. Those should be asked to a rabbi well-versed in the relevant laws who will ask questions on context and personal specifics to come to a good answer. This site can't substitute for this. Please don't let this deter you from coming back to learn with us.
